# How to use multiple Save() function in Controller | Spring boot | getting error for null parent key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

```
    @Transactional
    @PrePersist
    @PostMapping("/trans/incidentdetails")
    public ResponseEntity<IncidentCreationResponse> updateIncidentCost(@Valid @RequestBody IncidentCreation incidentCreation
                                          ) {


        IncidentOutageSum incidentOutageSum = new IncidentOutageSum();
        System.out.println("incidentNumber: " + incidentCreation.getIncidentNumber());
        System.out.println("incidentDate: " + incidentCreation.getIncidentDate());
        System.out.println("coeed : "+incidentCreation.getSumOfCoed());
        Long checkIncidentId = incidentDetailsRepository.getIncidentDetailsByIncidentNumber(incidentCreation.getIncidentNumber());
        System.out.println(checkIncidentId + " : checkIncidentId");
        String incidentDate = incidentCreation.incidentDate;
        LocalDate dtFmt = null;


try{
         dtFmt = LocalDate.parse(incidentDate,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-M-d")
                        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT));

        System.out.println("dtFmt : "+dtFmt);
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    IncidentCreationResponse customResponse = new IncidentCreationResponse();

    customResponse.setResponseCode(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.OK.value()));

    customResponse.setMessage("Incorrect Date Format for Incident Date");


    return new ResponseEntity<IncidentCreationResponse>(customResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

}

        if (checkIncidentId == null) {

            System.out.println("IF");

            IncidentDetails incidentDetails = new IncidentDetails();
            incidentDetails.setIncidentNumber(incidentCreation.getIncidentNumber());
            incidentDetails.setIncidentDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(dtFmt));



            IncidentDetails incidentDetails1 =
                    incidentDetailsRepository.save(incidentDetails);

            List<LobMaster> lobMaster = (List<LobMaster>) lobMasterRepository.findAll();

            List<IncidentOutage> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
         //   IncidentDetails incidentDetails1 = incidentDetailsRepository.getIncidentByIncidentNumber(incidentCreation.getIncidentNumber());
            for(int i =0 ; i<lobMaster.size() ; i++) {
                System.out.println(incidentDetails1.getId());
            //    System.out.println(i+" : lobMaster.get(i).getLobName().toUpperCase().trim() : "+lobMaster.get(i).getLobName().toUpperCase().trim());
               if(lobMaster.get(i).getLobName().toUpperCase().trim().toString().equals("PREPAID") ) {
                   System.out.println("PREPAID");

                   IncidentOutage incidentOutage = new IncidentOutage();
                   // incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails();
                  // LobMaster lobMaster1 = lobMasterRepository.getLobByName()
                   incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails(incidentDetails1);
                   incidentOutage.setLobMaster(lobMaster.get(i));
                   incidentOutage.setCodOrderDegrade(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().prepaid.codOrderDegrade);
                   incidentOutage.setCoedServiceCallDegraded(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().prepaid.coedServiceDegrade);
                   incidentOutage.setColTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().prepaid.colTransactionDip);
                   incidentOutage.setCoplTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().prepaid.coplTransactionDip);
                   System.out.println("incidentOutage : "+incidentOutage);
                   objectList.add(incidentOutage);
                 //  incidentOutageRepository.save(incidentOutage);

               }
                else if(lobMaster.get(i).getLobName().toUpperCase().trim().toString().equals("POSTPAID") ) {
                    System.out.println("POSTPAID");

                    IncidentOutage incidentOutage = new IncidentOutage();
                    // incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails();
                    // LobMaster lobMaster1 = lobMasterRepository.getLobByName()
                    incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails(incidentDetails1);
                    incidentOutage.setLobMaster(lobMaster.get(i));
                    incidentOutage.setCodOrderDegrade(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().postpaid.codOrderDegrade);
                    incidentOutage.setCoedServiceCallDegraded(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().postpaid.coedServiceDegrade);
                    incidentOutage.setColTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().postpaid.colTransactionDip);
                    incidentOutage.setCoplTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().postpaid.coplTransactionDip);
                    System.out.println("incidentOutage : "+incidentOutage);
                    objectList.add(incidentOutage);
                    //  incidentOutageRepository.save(incidentOutage);

                }

               else if(lobMaster.get(i).getLobName().toUpperCase().trim().toString().equals("BROADBAND") ) {
                    System.out.println("BROADBAND");

                    IncidentOutage incidentOutage = new IncidentOutage();
                    // incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails();
                    // LobMaster lobMaster1 = lobMasterRepository.getLobByName()
                    incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails(incidentDetails1);
                    incidentOutage.setLobMaster(lobMaster.get(i));
                    incidentOutage.setCodOrderDegrade(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().broadband.codOrderDegrade);
                    incidentOutage.setCoedServiceCallDegraded(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().broadband.coedServiceDegrade);
                    incidentOutage.setColTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().broadband.colTransactionDip);
                    incidentOutage.setCoplTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().broadband.coplTransactionDip);
                    System.out.println("incidentOutage : "+incidentOutage);
                    objectList.add(incidentOutage);
                    //  incidentOutageRepository.save(incidentOutage);

                }
               else if(lobMaster.get(i).getLobName().toUpperCase().trim().toString().equals("BLACK") ) {
                   System.out.println("BLACK");

                   IncidentOutage incidentOutage = new IncidentOutage();
                   // incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails();
                   // LobMaster lobMaster1 = lobMasterRepository.getLobByName()
                   incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails(incidentDetails1);
                   incidentOutage.setLobMaster(lobMaster.get(i));
                   incidentOutage.setCodOrderDegrade(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().black.codOrderDegrade);
                   incidentOutage.setCoedServiceCallDegraded(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().black.coedServiceDegrade);
                   incidentOutage.setColTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().black.colTransactionDip);
                   incidentOutage.setCoplTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().black.coplTransactionDip);
                   System.out.println("incidentOutage : "+incidentOutage);
                   objectList.add(incidentOutage);
                   //  incidentOutageRepository.save(incidentOutage);

               }
               else if(lobMaster.get(i).getLobName().toUpperCase().trim().toString().equals("B2B") ) {
                   System.out.println("B2B");

                   IncidentOutage incidentOutage = new IncidentOutage();
                   // incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails();
                   // LobMaster lobMaster1 = lobMasterRepository.getLobByName()
                   incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails(incidentDetails1);
                   incidentOutage.setLobMaster(lobMaster.get(i));
                   incidentOutage.setCodOrderDegrade(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().b2B.codOrderDegrade);
                   incidentOutage.setCoedServiceCallDegraded(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().b2B.coedServiceDegrade);
                   incidentOutage.setColTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().b2B.colTransactionDip);
                   incidentOutage.setCoplTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().b2B.coplTransactionDip);
                   System.out.println("incidentOutage : "+incidentOutage);
                   objectList.add(incidentOutage);
                   //  incidentOutageRepository.save(incidentOutage);

               }
               else if(lobMaster.get(i).getLobName().toUpperCase().trim().toString().equals("DTH") ) {
                   System.out.println("DTH");

                   IncidentOutage incidentOutage = new IncidentOutage();
                   // incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails();
                   // LobMaster lobMaster1 = lobMasterRepository.getLobByName()
                   incidentOutage.setIncidentDetails(incidentDetails1);
                   incidentOutage.setLobMaster(lobMaster.get(i));
                   incidentOutage.setCodOrderDegrade(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().dTH.codOrderDegrade);
                   incidentOutage.setCoedServiceCallDegraded(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().dTH.coedServiceDegrade);
                   incidentOutage.setColTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().dTH.colTransactionDip);
                   incidentOutage.setCoplTransactionDip(incidentCreation.getIncidentOutageData().dTH.coplTransactionDip);
                   System.out.println("incidentOutage : "+incidentOutage);
                   objectList.add(incidentOutage);
                   //  incidentOutageRepository.save(incidentOutage);

               }else{
                   System.out.println("No matching Lob");
               }

            }




            incidentOutageSum.setIncidentDetails(incidentDetails1);
            System.out.println("incidentCreation.sumOfCod: "+incidentCreation.getSumOfCod());
            incidentOutageSum.setSumOfCod(incidentCreation.getSumOfCod());
            incidentOutageSum.setSumOfCoed(incidentCreation.getSumOfCoed());
            incidentOutageSum.setSumOfCopl(incidentCreation.getSumOfCopl());
            incidentOutageSum.setSumOfCol(incidentCreation.getSumOfCol());



            Float totalCost = incidentCreation.getSumOfCod() + incidentCreation.getSumOfCoed() +
                    incidentCreation.getSumOfCopl() + incidentCreation.getSumOfCol();

            // addRecord(incidentCreation.getIncidentNumber(),incidentCreation.getIncidentDate());

            IncidentCreationResponse customResponse = new IncidentCreationResponse();

            customResponse.setResponseCode(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.CREATED.value()));
            customResponse.setTotalCost(totalCost);

            customResponse.setMessage("Record Saved Successfully");

            IncidentOutageSum incidentOutageSum1 =  incidentOutageSumRepository.save(incidentOutageSum);
            Iterable<IncidentOutage> incidentOutage = incidentOutageRepository.saveAll(objectList);

            return new ResponseEntity<IncidentCreationResponse>(customResponse, HttpStatus.CREATED);



        }else{
            System.out.println("ELSE");
            IncidentCreationResponse customResponse = new IncidentCreationResponse();

            customResponse.setResponseCode(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.OK.value()));

            customResponse.setMessage("Record Already Exists");


            return new ResponseEntity<IncidentCreationResponse>(customResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

        }
    }
```

I am getting error as:

```
Hibernate: insert into trx_incident_details (incident_date, incident_number, modified_date, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into trx_outage_sum (incident_id, modified_date, sum_of_cod, sum_of_coed, sum_of_col, sum_of_copl, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2022-06-11 00:31:51.612  WARN 20637 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
2022-06-11 00:31:51.612 ERROR 20637 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-02291: integrity constraint (OCCAL.FK_TRX_INCIDENT_DETAILS_1) violated - parent key not found
2022-06-11 00:31:51.612  INFO 20637 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2022-06-11 00:31:51.618  WARN 20637 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [OCCAL.FK_TRX_INCIDENT_DETAILS_1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
```

Comment: you'd better to simplify the code in order to make it readable and easily understandable

Answer (score 1):

The error is pointing out that the *parent key is not found* and your foreign key constraint has been *violated*: `FK_TRX_INCIDENT_DETAILS_1`

Which *could* mean you're inserting a record with a reference to something that does not exist.

For eg: In a simple classes-homework scenario, you have classes A, B, C. You're submitting homework to Class D

Comment: Hi Norman, Thanks for replying, i have run d code in debug mode, the parent id is there, i think the issue is related to some transaction management, which i don't know how to use. Even after the error too i can see the records gets inserted into the database but getting error for constraint

Comment: Hm, could you update your question with your findings if any? (debug results) - Since the error is from the database (constraints) - forget about Java for a second, try the queries you have with your data against your database directly, this solves a lot of things for me when debugging. If no error comes up as you try to find ways to reproduce it, with dummy and the exact same data you used for debugging, then we can go back to the java code